# VSCode C/C++ Intellisense issue: Undefined identifiers (Linux, Manjaro)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include-path, manjaro

- OS: Manjaro 18.1.5
- VS Code (OSS): 1.41.1
- C/C++ Extension: 0.26.3

Hi,

I have an issue using VS Code with the C/C++ extension. Some identifiers are not recognized by Intellisense, although my includePath in `c_cpp_properties.json` seems fine.

For instance here I am trying to display the current time with `time()` from the `ctime` library. VS Code tells me that the `time` identifier is undefined:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << time(nullptr) << endl; //--> "time" identifier is undefined
}
```

Here is my `c_cpp_properties.json` file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/linux",
                "/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/tr1"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

There is a `ctime` file at `/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/tr1/` as well as at `/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/` but changing the includePath to the latter doesn't change anything.

I know that many have similar issues but I couldn't find a solution that works for me, I don't know if it's specific to my linux distribution or whatsoever (see above for OS/Apps infos).

Thanks for your help,

FB.

Comment: Intellisense is *not* the compiler. It does *not* fully parse your code. It *will* sometimes get things wrong.

Comment: Only your actual compiler will provide definitive errors, when you actually compile your code. Intellisense is just trying to help you before that, but *don't* treat it as authoritative - it *is not* and it cannot be, since it needs to be fast and interactive (and parsing/compiling C++ is anything but).

Comment: `ctime.cpp` is not the same as the header `ctime`

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know but it souldn't fail on such simple things, it is just very annoying for autocompletion and code verification.

Comment: @user12808212 I suggest you open a bug report with Microsoft if their Intellisense does not live up to your expectations. They are the only ones who can help you. Me, I just stay away from tools like that entirely. I like being able to trust what my tools tell me, so I don't use autocomplete, intellisense etc. I just build my code and look at the compilers output.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks for your recommendation, I will report this bug if I find out this is not a configuration issue. I understand your point, I personnally like these kind of tools since they help me while coding.

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes I just found out it was a ```ctime``` file at both locations, not a ```ctime.cpp``` file. I edited my post so it is correct now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your settings.json file. You need to add the libraries manually in files.associations part. You can simply update the list like in the bottom:

```
{
"files.associations": {
        "cctype": "cpp",
        "cmath": "cpp",
        "cstddef": "cpp",
        "cstdlib": "cpp",
        "ctime": "cpp",
        "cwchar": "cpp",
        "random": "cpp",
        "ratio": "cpp",
        "iostream": "cpp"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to declare a Node* A = nullptr, and VSCode gave me the red squiggly too.  Here's how I fixed it:

Go over the "nullptr" with the error "nullptr is not defined..",
then click, "Quick Fix", which leads you to "Intellisense Configurations" page.

-> go to the bottom, above "Advanced Settings", and choose a more current C and C++ version.  I am using C++17 and C17 and they both support all language features.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Visual Studio Code version 1.67.1, because my `c_cpp_properties.json` had the "compilerPath" set to `cl.exe`, but my `tasks.json` had "command" set to `clang.exe`.

For me, VSCode reported `FILE` as being undefined, even though I had included `<stdio.h>`.

I resolved my issue by copying the path to `clang.exe` from "command" in `tasks.json`, and using that for "compilerPath" value in `c_cpp_properties.json`.

I presume that I alternately could have copied the `cl.exe` path into `tasks.json`.  My guess is that "compilerPath" and "command" should match, or at least be compatible with each other.